# AngularJS setting a default thumbnail on ng-thumb

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently trying to learn AngularJS, I am playing around with image upload functions and using ng-thumb to preview the image file being uploaded. What I am trying to do right now is set the ng-thumb to show a default image and have that image be overriden when a new image is uploaded.

```
<div class="row-fluid col-md-12 text-center" ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
     <div ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 200, width: 300}"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to set a default image for ng-thumb? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's likely the only solution you have is to place an `ng-if` on this `div` that shows it only if there are items and an alternative `ng-if` on another `div` that defines a static image.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Image() with JavaScript API explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

and use this image with ng-thumb. ( ng-thumb = "{ file: newImage, height: 200, width: 300}" )